# ActiveRecord querying on multiple joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a users table associated with posts, 
posts associated with comments,
comments associated with likes(status: 1,2,3,4). How can I sort the users based on likes count where status having 2 or 3 or 4.

Below I have tried:
named scope in likes model to get status with 1,2,3,4

```
Post.joins(comments: :likes).merge(Like.status_count)
```

But failing to the sort based on count. Any help

Answer (score 0):

For ordering active record objects you can use `order` method, For Example

Assume a Users Database and i want to order it based on name, then we can do

```
User.order(:name)  //Returns Users on ascending order of name
User.order(name :desc) //Returs Users in descending order of name
```

Similary you can try

```
Post.joins(comments: :likes).merge(Like.active.order(:status_count))
```

The documentation for the `order` method can be found in [this](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order) link

Comment: I missed one more scope actually it is like Like.status_count.active. Here  status_count and active both are scopes. Is there any way to join scope in your answer ?

Comment: @RebelRider Can you try the query updated in my answer

Comment: It is giving the error unknown column status_count SELECT COUNT(status_count) FROM `likes`

Comment: what does `status_count` return, You can use order only based on colomns in the table not based on scopes

Comment: So here is the requirement i need to sort the user records whose status with  active likes. active is the scope to get the active likes and status_count will give only the status with 1 or 2 etc..,

Comment: Why would you use `.all` wouldn't `User.order(:name)` return all the users ordered by name anyway?

Comment: Yes it will, my mistake @MikeHeft